# Perl XMLout file doesn't match format of the input file

Tags: xml, perl

I use an older version of Perl for some work reasons, v5.6.1

I did the following :

```
#!usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use XML::Simple;

my $xml = new XML::Simple;  # create object
my $inputxml = $xml->XMLin("C:\\original.xml");
print "\nInput XML File read... OK\n\n";

my $path = "C:\\output.xml";
open my $fh, ">", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";
print $fh XMLout($inputxml);
close $fh or warn "$0: close $path: $!";
```

I had to write to file in the above method because, this method below did not work :

`#my $outputfile = $xml->XMLout($inputxml, OutputFile => 'output.xml');`

If you look closely the output.xml does not match the original.xml at all. The newly written output.xml file looks like :

```
</InstanceOverride>
<InstanceOverride name="NetworkInterfaces">
  <CELL mlinkType="0" ethInterfaceName="#0" name="RtfCsm" />
</InstanceOverride>
```

instead of looking like :

```
<InstanceOverride>
    <NetworkInterfaces>
        <CELL>
            <RtfCsm
              mlinkType="0"
              ethInterfaceName="#0"/>
        </CELL>
    </NetworkInterfaces>
</InstanceOverride>
```

But they are both xml. What do I do to fix this output format? I cannot use this new wierd format, I need the original XML format. What is a SAX format?

I need help!

Here is another input XML file to test foo.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Deploy xmlns="http://www.dnsleak.com/view">    <SystemWideOverride>
        <Bearers>
            <ENB>
                <DrbProfile
                  instanceNumber="7">
                    <PdcpProfile
                      DlDataForwarding="false"
                      UlDataForwarding="false"/>
                </DrbProfile>
            </ENB>
        </Bearers>
    </SystemWideOverride>
</Deploy>
```

Comment: So don't use XML::Simple, the most complex XML parser out there.

Comment: `KeyAttr => []` will help

Comment: if you can't get XML::Simple to behave the way you want, read its dos, especially https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#WHERE-TO-FROM-HERE

Comment: Additionally, `ForceArray => 1` and `ForceContent => 1` will avoid some other changes.

Answer (score 2):

`XML::Simple` stores its XML as a hash of hashes. When you output those hashes, it's very likely that you will get a completely different output. After all, there's no set order on hashes, so it's very likely that your XML entity order will be different. Plus, there's a number of ways a particular XML syntax could be implemented in a series of hashes-- which is what you've hit.

You can try playing around with the various parameters and methods to tweak `XML::Simple` to do what you want. However, this warning embedded in the `XML::Simple` documentation for a reason:

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.

I still use `XML::Simple` as a quick and dirty way to parse an XML file for analysis -- for example, parsing Ant `build.xml` files to find out which targets are building jar files. However, I wouldn't depend upon it to be able to keep my XML structure accurate.